# Denoting tolerable range for common values in two sequences

Tags: notation

Given set ***X*** and set ***Y***, common values can be denoted in a new set via set intersection, so: ***Z*** = ***X*** ∩ ***Y***. However, let's say set ***X*** = {1,2,3,4} and set ***Y*** = {1.3, 2.3, 2.7 4.3}. All values in set ***X*** are within .3 of some value in set ***Y***, yet ***Z*** = ***X*** ∩ ***Y*** would be empty since the values aren't exactly the same. How can you specify that set ***Z*** includes the intersection of values in ***X*** and ***Y***, within the tolerable range of plus or minus .3?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the so-called $0.3$ neighborhood  $A^{(0.3)}$ of $A$ as the set of all numbers $x$ such that $|x-a| \leq 0.3$ for some $a \in A$. Then the property you have is $ B \subseteq A^{(0.3)}$.

General definition:  $\epsilon$ neighborhood  $A^{(\epsilon)}$ of a set $A$ is the set of all numbers $x$ such that $d(x,a) \leq \epsilon$ for some $a \in A$. [ $(d(x,a)$ is the distance between $x$ and $a$]. This definition makes sense in any metric space.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion